# Pandas dataframe Timedelta format: with days or with cumulative hours

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, timedelta

I am trying to understand that depending on what does pandas show Timedelta values either with 'days' or with cumulative number of hours.

In the following example, I take a Timedelta column and calculate its cumulative sum:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                      

In [2]: pd.__version__                                                                                                                                                           
Out[2]: '1.0.3'

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame( 
   ...:     [ 
   ...:         "01:07:37", 
   ...:         "13:16:44", 
   ...:         "11:09:56", 
   ...:         "12:05:00", 
   ...:         "01:33:01", 
   ...:     ], 
   ...:     columns=["Duration"], 
   ...: )                                                                                                                                                                        

In [4]: df.loc[:, 'Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration']) 
   ...: df.loc[:, 'Cumulative'] = df['Duration'].cumsum() 
   ...:  
   ...: df                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[4]: 
  Duration      Cumulative
0 01:07:37 0 days 01:07:37
1 13:16:44 0 days 14:24:21
2 11:09:56 1 days 01:34:17
3 12:05:00 1 days 13:39:17
4 01:33:01 1 days 15:12:18
```

In the resulting dataframe the new column (`Cumulative`) shows 'days' while the original column (`Duration`) shows cumulative number of hours.

The two columns are of the same data type.

```
In [5]: df.dtypes                                                                                                                                                                
Out[5]: 
Duration      timedelta64[ns]
Cumulative    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Furthermore, when I look at the first row it shows the 'number of hours' format, but, when I look at individual values, it returns them in the Timedelta('N days HH:MM:SS') format.

```
In [6]: df.iloc[0, :]                                                                                                                                                            
Out[6]: 
Duration     01:07:37
Cumulative   01:07:37
Name: 0, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [7]: df['Duration'][0], df['Cumulative'][0]                                                                                                                                   
Out[7]: (Timedelta('0 days 01:07:37'), Timedelta('0 days 01:07:37'))
```

So my question is that why does this change occur and how can I control it?

## EDIT

As @Moosa Saadat and @Quang Hoang pointed out, the shift between the different formats occurs when **any** of the Timedelta values surpasses the 24-hour threshold.

As I did not find a built-in way to do the shift, here is a small helper function that prints Timedelta values in a cumulative hours format.

```py
In [4]: def days_to_cumhours(timedelta): 
   ...:     hours = timedelta.components[0] * 24 + timedelta.components[1] 
   ...:  
   ...:     return f"{hours:0>2}:{timedelta.components[2]:0>2}:{timedelta.components[3]:0>2}"                                                                                                                                                                  

In [5]: df['Cumulative'].apply(days_to_cumhours)                                                                                                                                 
Out[5]: 
0    01:07:37
1    14:24:21
2    25:34:17
3    37:39:17
4    39:12:18
Name: Cumulative, dtype: object
```

Comment: It's just how pandas chooses to **display** the `timedelta` once the duration surpasses 1 day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why does this change occur?

The list of time strings have all values less than 24 hours. Which means they all have `day = 0`. Therefore, when you print the df, `pandas` doesn't display it. If you change some value, let's say `12:05:00` to `25:05:00`, you  will get the following output

```py
         Duration      Cumulative
0 0 days 01:07:37 0 days 01:07:37
1 0 days 13:16:44 0 days 14:24:21
2 0 days 11:09:56 1 days 01:34:17
3 1 days 01:05:00 2 days 02:39:17
4 0 days 01:33:01 2 days 04:12:18
```

Now, as we have different `days` in our `Duration` column, pandas display it's values.

#### How can I control it?

You don't have to worry about the difference in output. When, you need to get the values you can use `components()` function which returns a namedtuple

```py
print(df['Duration'].iloc[0].components)
```

output:

```py
Components(days=0, hours=1, minutes=7, seconds=37, milliseconds=0, microseconds=0, nanoseconds=0)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, actually this is really straightforward. I was confused because not all the values were more than one day. I am still curious if I can render the format to the 'cumulative hours' format in an easy way.

Comment: @nocibambi I am not sure if there is any builtin function. So, your helper function might be the only way. If you are only interested in **number of hours**, something like  `df['Duration'].iloc[0].total_seconds() / 3600` will do the work. But, again, if you are looking for precise time, your helper function does a great job

Comment: @Moose Saadat  My main concern is rather presentation so this is why I insist on this format. Otherwise, of course, I would not mind the days or could, indeed, calculate the hours. I just assumed that there might be a built-in solution as the two formats are already implemented and in use.